Getting 'Unexpected token, expected "," ' in typescript even after deleting all the content in file
I'm using Visual studio code latest version (Version 1.95.1). Facing a issue when I copy the content from a notepad++ or notepad application and pasting in visual studio editor.

In my code I have written, I copied the URL from notepad and passed in the visual code editor. Text I copied is 'https://conduit.bondaracademy.com/'.
After I write the code, visual studio is showing some error.

Even after deleting the test function, it was throwing the same error. -> deleted line 4 to 6 in above screen shot

Even after deleting the entire content in file also, it throwing the error. Deleted line 1 also from above screen shot.

Only Choice I have is using content without pasting anything from notepad. After pasting any value, one or other error is shown.
Error clearly says, line 5 in my initial code.

Any particular IDE setting I have use so copy paste works without any issue.
Regards,

install the package npm install @playwright/test and import them this way import { test, expect } from '@playwright/test';

That the same in my first statement. 'import { test, expect } from '@playwright/test';'. Even script is running fine, but still shows the error in editor

Isnt it @ missing before the playwright
